# Texture not applying correctly in Blender

Tags: texturing, node-editor

So, I'm new to Blender and I started to mess around with nodes. And I tried importing a face texture to my head model and it imported it quite weirdly.

Nodes:

[image: nodes]
Face Texture:

[image: nodes]
Blender View:

[image: nodes]

Comment: I am not good with texturing and nodes but a guess, its because you used it as and alpha. Just erase the alpha connection. You want to use it only as a image texture right?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly you want to map the face image onto one face of your object, and color the rest with a simple color where the image is transparent?
It can be done with simple UV Mapping, and using the Alpha channel to drive the mixing factor.
[image]